# Saving product of code as a text file

Tags: file, save

Hi I was wondering with the following code how I could save it as a text file. In Word, Excel or even just note pad. 
Thanks

```
print 'The Solar Atitude is:', ("%.1f" % Altitude),'°'
print 'The Solar Azimuth is:', ("%.1f" % Azimuth),'°'
print 'The unprotected window area is:', ("%.0f" % Unprotected_Window_Area),'mm^2'
print 'The Shading Transmittance of the indented window using the given data is:', ("%.1f" % Shading_Transmittance_Percentage),'%'
```

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```
with open('test.txt', 'wt') as f:
    f.write('The Solar Atitude is:%.1f°\n' % (Altitude,))
    f.write('The Solar Azimuth is:%.1f°\n' % (Azimuth,))
    f.write('The Shading ... is:%.1f%%\n' % (Shading_Transmittance_Percentage,))
```

Comment: Could you help with the last line, I think because the unit is % it is assuming there is another argument:    f.write('The Shading Transmittance Pecentage of the indented window using the given data is:%.1f%\n' % (Shading_Transmittance_Percentage,))